# Application menu is enabled even if a modal dialog box is open

Tags: macos, qt, macos-carbon

I have an application where I can launch a modal dialog box over a main window. The main window has some network activity going on in background which updates my background UI. Due to this the application menu becomes accessible even if the modal dialog is open.

How can I avoid this? Any help is appreciated.

I am using Mac, Qt, Carbon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable Application menu on Mac OS X, it's always "active" BUT you can disable actions you don't want to be used while dialog is visible

Comment: Thanks for downvoting, but as you can see, there is no other answer for this question. It's a "natural" behaviour on Mac OS X that menubar is always active

Comment: Right, the proper thing to do is disable individual items as needed, not the entire menu. Apple Human Interface Guidelines say "Even if all of the items in a menu or submenu are unavailable, the menu or submenu title is not dimmed. The user can still open the menu, but all of its items are dimmed to indicate that these items are not available in the present context."

Answer (score 0):

You can have the modal dialog create its own menubar, which will override the the mainwindow's while the dialog is shown.

If you don't want to allow any actions, just create an empty QMenuBar with the dialog as its parent. You don't even have to show it. Qt will find it and promote it to the global menu bar automagically.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in Ubuntu, so may be this will solve your problem in Mac OS X as well. It is simple, just disable the `QMenu.nativeMenuBar` property of the main menu bar, i.e. `menuBar->setNativeMenuBar(false)`. See the accepted answer here: [Global application menu active in modal dialog box (on Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035662/global-application-menu-active-in-modal-dialog-box-on-linux)